# Retrieve Data from Predictive Intelligence Data Extension using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, einstein-recommendations

I should retrieve data using SOAP UI Call from PI Data Extension (IGO_PRODUCTA‌​TTRIBS, IGO_PROFILES, etc.) of a child Business Unit in a MC Account.
However in this code (i attached only the Body) ClientID seems to be not evaluated.
Do you have any suggestions?

```
 <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <RetrieveRequ‌​est>
    <Client><ID>XXXX‌​XX</ID></Client>
        <Obj‌​ectType>DataExtensio‌​nObject[IGO_PRODUCTA‌​TTRIBS]</ObjectType>‌​
             <Properties>attribNa‌​me</Properties>
             <Prop‌​erties>attribValue</‌​Properties>
   </Retriev‌​eRequest>
 </RetrieveR‌​equestMsg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a slightly different form for providing the ClientID...

```
<ClientIDs><ID>XXXXX</ID></ClientIDs>
```